# Change HorizontalGridLinesBrush only for selected Row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, gridlines

In a WPF ´DataGrid´ the Color of the Horizontal Grid Line can be modified by the `HorizontalGridLinesBrush` Property.

Some Items have a boolean Property set to true so I want to **highlight** them with the Horizontal Grid Line Brush set to another Color.

Is it possible to change the Color of the Horizontal Grid Line only for cetain Rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush` is set per `DataGrid` so you cannot change it per row but you could replace default horizontal line behaviour by disabling horizontal grid lines and creating custom `DataGridRow` style

```xml
<DataGrid ... GridLinesVisibility="Vertical">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Style.Triggers>

                <!-- this will trigger when row is selected -->
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">                        
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>

                <!-- this will trigger when Highlight property of the view model is true -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlight}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```